# How to allow Image3D to be dragged on Wolfram Cloud?

Tags: graphics, manipulate, graphics3d, wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

I have an 3D image as below, and then I deployed it to Cloud with Public permission. However, in the cloud, it is just a "static image", and user can't drag the image interactively (to change the point of view) as what we do in Mathematica.

```
id = "7ea03ea6b5df8acae178578dd80eca8af42e1cd16df8d4eea370599d649e5a89";
dataCube = BlockchainGet[id];
myColorFunction = (If[# == 0, Transparent, Hue[#, 1, 1, 0.1]] &);
show1 = Show[Image3D[dataCube, ColorFunction -> myColorFunction, Method -> {"VolumeLighting" -> "EnhancedEdge", "InterpolateValues" -> True}]
, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, Background -> Black, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {Style["z", Bold, 16], Style["y", Bold, 16], Style["x", Bold, 16]}]
CloudDeploy[show1, Permissions -> "Public"]
```

How can I allow it to be interactive in cloud? Thanks!

Output:-

[image]

```
CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/f7d8b9bd-549f-4a75-bec0-ecc799b1aee0"]
```

Comment: Not supported yet